# View Cube - How to find the vertices of the top view to bounding box of the object

Tags: three.js

Here I'm trying to capture the top view vertices of the bounding box and push that to the camera position for the viewcube module. So, how to capture the top view points of the bounding box of the cube and pass that to the camera in a button click. Here's the fiddle which what I tried
https://jsfiddle.net/97mqhLf8/

```
 var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true
        });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


        // scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));
        // scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(5));

        var geom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(4, 4, 4);
        var mats = [
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff00ff }),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 }),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 }),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff }),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ffff })
        ];

        var box = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mats);
        scene.add(box);
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
        var mat = new THREE.Matrix4();
        var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(box, 0xff0000);
        scene.add(bbox);

        console.log(bbox.min);
        console.log(bbox.max);

        $('#rotateRight').on('click', function (e) {
            RotateBuilding('rotateRight');
        });

        function turn(angle) {
            box.rotation.y += angle;
        }
        var angle = 0;
        var radius = 10;

        function animate() {

            // Use Math.cos and Math.sin to set camera X and Z values based on angle. 
            camera.position.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            camera.position.z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
            angle += 1;

        }

        document.querySelector('#cube__face--front').addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("leftcube__face--left view");
            // camera.position.set(0, 0, 12);
            turn(Math.PI * 0.5);
            camera.position.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            camera.position.z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
            angle += 0.01;
            // roates the box and camera is not updated
            console.log(box.rotation.y);
            controls.update();
            render();
        });

        document.querySelector('#cube__face--left').addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("leftcube__face--left view");
            // camera.position.set(0, 0, 12);
            turn(Math.PI * 0.5);
            camera.position.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            camera.position.z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
            angle += 0.01;
            // roates the box and camera is not updated
            console.log(box.rotation.y);
            controls.update();
            render();
        });
        document.querySelector('#cube__face--bottom').addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("bottom view");
            // transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateX(180deg) translateZ(-50px);
            // box.rotateX(THREE.Math.degToRad(90));
            // box.rotateY(THREE.Math.degToRad(180));
            // box.translateZ(-50);
            // camera.position.x = camera.position.y + 90*Math.PI/180;

            // camera.position.set(0, -10, 0);
            // distance = -25;
            // camera.translateY(distance);
            // controls.update();
            camera.position.x = 1.1239808601379084;
            camera.position.y = -9.999999999994992;
            camera.position.z = 0.000009999368316182553;
            // x:
            // 1.1239808601379084
            // e - 7
            // y: -9.999999999994992
            // z: 0.000009999368316182553
            render();
        });

        document.querySelector('#cube__face--top').addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("Top view");
            var distance;
            camera.position.z = distance;
            // rotation.x += 0.01;
            distance2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            distance2.copy(camera.position);
            camera.position.x = distance * Math.sin(distance2.x) * Math.cos(distance2.y);
            camera.position.y = distance * Math.sin(distance2.y);
            camera.position.z = distance * Math.cos(distance2.z) * Math.cos(distance2.y);
        });


        $('#rotateRight').on('click', function (e) {
            RotateBuilding('rotateRight');
        });

        function RotateBuilding(toShowSide) {
            var selectedFace;
            $.each(geom.faces, function (i, fc) {
                if (fc.side == toShowSide) {
                    selectedFace = fc;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            var vector = selectedFace.normal.clone();
            var center = myMesh.geometry.boundingSphere.center.clone();

            var camPos = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(center, vector.setLength(50));

            camera.position.copy(camPos);
            controls.target.copy(center);

        }
        document.querySelector('#cube__face--top').addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("top view");
            box.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), 90 * (Math.PI / 180));
            controls.update();
            render();
        });

        renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

            mat.extractRotation(camera.matrixWorldInverse);

            cube.style.transform = `translateZ(-300px) ${getCameraCSSMatrix(mat)}`;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            // console.log(box.rotation);


        });

        function getCameraCSSMatrix(matrix) {

            var elements = matrix.elements;

            return 'matrix3d(' +
                epsilon(elements[0]) + ',' +
                epsilon(-elements[1]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[2]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[3]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[4]) + ',' +
                epsilon(-elements[5]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[6]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[7]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[8]) + ',' +
                epsilon(-elements[9]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[10]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[11]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[12]) + ',' +
                epsilon(-elements[13]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[14]) + ',' +
                epsilon(elements[15]) +
                ')';

        }
        function render() {
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            controls.update();
        }
        function epsilon(value) {

            return Math.abs(value) < 1e-10 ? 0 : value;

        }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear to me what you want to do? Can you please elaborate in more detail?

Comment: Sorry @Mugen87. The things is I'm trying to take the bounding box of the object and  to set that planes direction of the bounding box as X, XN, Y, YN, Z, ZN axis to the 6 phases and to set the position of the camera to the respective direction of the phase when we select any phase of the bounding box(which is the view of the object)

Comment: Am I clear this time. Sorry! Correct if I'm wrong @Mugen87